# Handle more than 5000 items in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I am setting up a Flow that can read an Excel file and insert the items to a list in SharePoint Online.

However, the Flow fails when there are more than 5000 rows in the excel.

Even when I set an item limit of 5000, I get this error:

```
Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Apply_to_each' at line '1' and column '5658': 'The number of foreach items limit exceeded for action 'Apply_to_each': maximum '5000' and actual '5120'.'.
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

The free license allows up to 5000 `for each items`, while several other licenses allow 100,000. From the documentation:
[image]

This is **per flow**, so a workaround like *having multiple excel files with 5000 lines* or *several loops with a variable where the line number is stored* will not work.

Answer (score 0):

We had an approximate count on the rows that would need to be imported.
So we had multiple read excel actions.

- In the first one, we read the first 5000 rows and insert them to the list.
- In the next action, we skip the first 5000 items and read the next 5000; then insert them to the list.

We had enough actions to cover all the expected rows, and the Flow is working fine.